# OpenSTA script error

Tags: stress-testing

I am trying to learn openSTA tool.

I recorded the script and then when I clicked on replay i got following error,

```
Compiling... TESTSCRIPT.HTP

        "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04
*************************************************************************************************************************************
TESTSCRIPT.HTP(27) : error (badrecsiz), Source Line is Too Long

    CONSTANT    S_cookie_3_0    = "ASP.NET_SessionId=30hreg5512fghcebgeqzn4na"
*********************************************************************
TESTSCRIPT.HTP(28) : error (exttxt), Unexpected Text Encountered Following Statement

                "Cookie: "+S_cookie_3_0}
                           ************ 
TESTSCRIPT.HTP(79) : error (undefvar), Undefined Variable
scl: info (endnoobj), TESTSCRIPT.HTP Completed with 3 Diagnostics - Object Deleted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Cat=0&Number=462105&an=0&page=0#Post462105). The String in the script was too  long just truncated some characters in it.